# After= doesn't work with devices in systemd

Tags: linux, networking, systemd

I want to put my wifi interface `wlp3s0` into 4addr mode before adding it to the bridge `br0`, so I write following `/etc/systemd/system/4addr2.service`:

```
[Unit]
Description=Put interface into 4addr mode
Before=sys-subsystem-net-devices-br0.device
After=sys-subsystem-net-devices-wlp3s0.device

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/sbin/iw dev wlp3s0 set 4addr on
RemainAfterExit=true

[Install]
WantedBy=sys-subsystem-net-devices-br0.device
```

However I see that this service runs BEFORE `sys-subsystem-net-devices-wlp3s0.device` unit:

[image]

`jounalctl` also didn't give explanation why `4addr2` started before `sys-subsystem-net-devices-wlp3s0.device`:

```
$ sudo journalctl -u 4addr2
-- Logs begin at Thu 2020-09-03 08:44:03 EDT, end at Thu 2020-09-03 08:48:53 EDT. --
Sep 03 08:44:05 router systemd[1]: Starting Put interfaces into 4addr mode...
Sep 03 08:44:05 router iw[393]: command failed: No such device (-19)
Sep 03 08:44:05 router systemd[1]: 4addr2.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=237/KEYRING
Sep 03 08:44:05 router systemd[1]: 4addr2.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Sep 03 08:44:05 router systemd[1]: Failed to start Put interfaces into 4addr mode.
```

How can I understand why my service started before interface device initialized?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before= and After= only have an effect when sorting jobs that are already part of the job queue, whereas .device units aren't usually part of it – they're not "started", they just pop up out of nowhere, because they only represent what has happened externally.

So you will additionally need to list the same wlp3s0.device in **`Requires=`** or even **`BindsTo=`**. That way systemd *will* try to "start" the .device unit (which is defined as waiting for the device to appear), and this will make After= work.

But for a related reason, it won't help to order a service Before=br0. Doing so *will not* delay the creation of br0, nor the addition of other interfaces to it, because both of those things happen externally and not via systemd.

If you are currently using systemd-networkd to do this, you might need to remove that and instead use the same custom .service to assign the bridge:

```
ExecStart=/sbin/iw dev wlp3s0 set 4addr on
ExecStart=/sbin/ip link set wlp3s0 master br0
```

(There might also be other approaches, such as *creating* a whole new wireless dev that already has 4addr enabled from the beginning, using `iw ... interface add` on the same phy.)